# Why “king & queen” but not “roi & reine”?

Tags: etymology, history

If I am not mistaken, modern English language has a large influence from Old French through the Norman invasion by William the Conqueror in 1066 and subsequent Norman monarchs.

However, the modern words used in reference to male and female rulers in a monarchy are ***[king](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=king&allowed_in_frame=0)*** and ***[queen](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=queen)***, derived from Old English *cyning* and *cwen* respectively.

But if the new rulers brought with them their language, why aren't monarchs today called something derived from *roi* and *reine*, or something along those lines?

Is it something the new rulers chose, maybe to bring themselves closer to their new subjects? Or did the population keep calling the new rulers *cyning* and *cwen*, regardless of the language the rulers brought with them, and it simply stuck? Or is it something completely different?

Comment: Maybe the subjects refused to change (most laypersons spoke 'English' rather than French) - language follows the people.

Comment: We only use 'roi' and 'reine' if we're about to eat them.

Comment: Although we don't use *roi*, we do use the adjective form *royal*.

Answer (score 13):

Even if "William the Conqueror" thought himself ***Guillaume, roi d'Angleterre***, most of his English subjects would have no idea what a ***roi d'Angleterre*** was, much less a  ***Guillaume***. No doubt William wanted to be known as just the next king, not the founder of a new order. But I think that was not the reason "king" remained in English.

The English terms "[earl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earl)", "[sheriff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheriff)" and "[knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight)" were retained by the Norman rulers to promote continuity. French terms were used for concepts not previously part of English government such as "[marquess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquess)". (Some concepts were mixed, like "[duke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duke)". Some French terms were alternatives to English terms, like "[count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count)".)

It would be obvious here that the Normans were more interested in exploiting the English apple cart than upsetting it. They actually did both, but not by attempting to turn England into Normandy. Even if William were King of England and Duke of Normandy, England and Normandy remained separate concerns.

It cannot be surprising that "king" and "queen"  remained in English given the Norman attitude.

Comment: This sounds entirely plausible, but do you have any sources?

Comment: @ Readin... what is the specific concern?

Comment: Well I am not sure they wouldn't have understood what a Guillaume was, seeing how the name most likely derives from the same Old Germanic name as William does, but I think I see your point. Even if Angles and Saxons had retained administrative terms from the variant of Latin they found upon their arrival, the Roman Empire was not a kingdom so they wouldn't have retained Latin terms for royalty. Would you then say it is something the new rulers chose? And, as a curiosity, do you know if Anglo-Saxons retained any administrative terms from Latin?

Comment: @Carvo Loco.......As far as I know, the Anglo-Saxons found no government in Britain familiar to their ways. I mentioned "duke" in the answer, which was from Latin, but not from Imperial administration. The Anglo-Saxons had little permanent organized government and only outside pressure caused England to unite under one King/, and that not an all-powerful one.Most of the Latin acquired into English before The Conquest was connected to the Church. The Anglo-Saxons had a notion of general equality in their communities with leaders seen as "first among equals"; this was  disturbed by the Normans.

Comment: @J.Taylor My specific concern is that the answer sounds like a guess from a well)-educated person. Since I don't know you (and I hope you don't take offense - since I don't know you I certainly don't mean to offend  you), how can I have confidence in the correctness of the answer?

Comment: @ Readin.... I provided citations for what I thought were important issues. As to other issuesm I can take them one at a time and cite  the same..

Comment: @ Readin... I did not mean to leave it at that. One basis for the answer was the condition, politically of the Channel Islands. By the reckoning of the governments of  those Islands, they are part of Normandy, and, have never been part of England, Great Britain or the UK.. The different institutions and language of government supports the notion that England was never the object of a radical :"Normanization" of its government.. That is  getting away from language, though, so I did not include any of that in the answer.. I am not offended by your comment . I hope I can satisfy ytour concerns..

Comment: This explanation's weakness is that the administrative work would no longer have taken place in OE with Latin replacing it rapidly after the Conquest. ME would also come into use soon; but at least after mid-12th century, I don't think there's much evidence for public use of OE. Instead, I would attribute the kingship remaining English as evidence of the strength of the Anglicisation of the Normans through interactions with the remaining AS nobility. The rebellions in the early reign of William may have thwarted this, but the premise remains relevant for the next two and three hundred years.

Comment: @gktscrk I do not think you are much in conflict with my answer. ":Administrative work" work was hardly done in English before the Conquest  as it had hardly ever been done,  Latin was the administrative language of Western Europe as it was the one language scribes would be fluent in,. There were no common languages within regions, including England.  Remember that William the Bastard did not share a common first language with Richard the First. I do not think the use of Latin after the Conquest means much about  "Normanization" or Anglicization. Do you believe I am in error here?

Comment: @J.Taylor When it comes to word origins it's common for people to see connections and assume they are true without actually knowing for sure. For example I was told long ago that "woman" meant "man with a womb". I've seen a lengthy diatribe explaining that the word "woman" is actually unrelated to the word man. Or, for another example, when I learned some Chinese and some Japanese I noticed that "ke ai" and "kawaii", both meaning cute in their respective language, are so similar that they _had_ to be related. They're not. How do I know you are correct and not just fitting things without proof?

Comment: @J.Taylor I didn't downvote your answer. I would like to upvote it because it is well written, detailed, and clear. But I don't want to upvote something that might be wrong and thus perpetuate one of those facts that is known by many people but is untrue.

Comment: @ Readin I am curious what I might have written that could be in error, or the beginnings of "folk etymology",  I cited 3 terms in English that might reasonably been the targets for disuse in any general "Normanization": of England, I understood the question was of why "king" and "queen" were still in use. One cannot get into the head of William the Bastard; we can know of some of his actions. He became "King". "Sheriffs" still held office, loyal Earls were not required to become "Counts".  People are still "knighted", not made "chevalier".  no attempt on the language of governance is obvious

Comment: @ Readin.... So, we still have "king": and "queen"  because William chose not to "normanize" English institutions. Clearly, had he wanted to do so, he would have. He did strengthen the position of "King", claiming some authority that had previously been held locally.  "King" John came to understand that the  .English institutions were not so much replaced by Continental notions when his hand was forced on to the Magna Carta. That various French dialects came to  be spoken in England and radically changed the English Language does not mean there was a plot afoot to make England Normandy. (more)

Comment: @ Readin... certainly no plot to replace the English names for institutions. If there are specific issues with my answer, I will address them. I have no fear of what I know, but of what I do not know.. I know I can be in error, so I do not fear that. I suspect some have read into my answer things I do not think are there. This I do not know.

Comment: @J.Taylor: No, I don't think you're in error. I just think that we cannot really know. Also, from what I understand at least pre-Wessex supremacy, legislation and such was in OE (local dialect perhaps but even so)?

Comment: @ gktscrk.. I will certainly give you that Ethelbert, King of Kent, had his laws codified in his own language.  He was, however, the first English king to adopt Christianity, and so, had no tradition of recording laws in Latin.. That may well have encouraged use of local languages in writing, but, still, Latin remained the primary language of writing, including most of Bede;s work.

Comment: I think we'd still not know what a Guillame was, to be quite honest...!

Comment: I find it fascinating that England had a kind of kind of peer-based rule until William showed up. And ironic that it was the French who later beheaded their king and became more... peer-based. And even *more* ironic that the French refer to the English as... 'Les Anglo-Saxons, even today...

Answer (score 12):

William claimed the existing title of King held by Harold.  French became less popular in large part due to the 100 years war.  Henry IV was the first to take his oath in English. Henry V was a native English speaker.

The last thing William wanted was to invent a new title and leave the title "King of England" open to be claimed by one of his many enemies and rivals. The whole point of the Norman conquest was to claim the title "King of England" for William.

Comment: The last thing William wanted was to invent a new title and leave the title "King of England" open to be claimed by one of his many enemies and rivals. The whole point of the Norman conquest was to claim the title "King of England" for William.

Comment: You should move/copy your comment into your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, MikeJRamsey56, and especially for your helpful added comment. Following Makyen's suggestion, I have taken the liberty to copy your comment to the main body of your answer, although it is pending review by peers.

Answer (score 3):

One reasonable explanation is that the Normans wanted to be seen as the legitimate heirs to an existing title rather than as conquerors who granted themselves a new title.

Having said that the key legal terms and adjectives such as monarch, crown, sovereign and royal are all Latin or Old French in origin.

This can also be related to the fact that terms for livestock tend to have Old English origins (Cow, Pig etc) while terms for meat as food tend to be french.